# How to use DataHandler in Symfony command controller in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

```php
class RemoveHiddenPages extends Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command 
{

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {
      Bootstrap::initializeBackendAuthentication();
      $uid = someuid;
      $cmd['pages'][$uid]['delete'] = 1;
      $dataHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);
      $dataHandler->start([], $cmd);
      $dataHandler->process_cmdmap(); 
      // ....
```

I try to run the command from the command line. This results in an exception:

```
Tue, 17 Mar 2020 10:14:15 +0100 [CRITICAL] request="684c29a15bc6b" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": 
Core: Exception handler (CLI): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Argument 1 passed to
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Session\Backend\DatabaseSessionBackend::update() must be of the type string, null given, 
called in /site/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Authentication/AbstractUserAuthentication.php on line 1311 
| TypeError thrown in file /site/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Session/Backend/DatabaseSessionBackend.php in line 159 
- {"exception":{"xdebug_message":"\nTypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Session\\Backend\\DatabaseSessionBackend::update()
must be of the type string, null given, called in ....
```

In `DataHandler::deletePages()` a flash message is sent. This seems to cause the problem, as the session is not initialized. Is it possible to use the DataHandler in command controllers?

The example is based on:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html

I am using TYPO3 9.5.14

Comment: The flash message is only rendered if there was an error, so you need to debug and fix that first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the error does not occur, this seems to work fine. It looks like the bug is related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look into in2code/migration. There is a DataHandler call to move pages via symfony command: https://github.com/einpraegsam/migration/blob/master/Classes/Command/DataHandlerCommand.php

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int 
{
    $command = [];
    $command['pages'][(int)$input->getArgument('startPid')][$input->getArgument('action')]
        = (int)$input->getArgument('targetPid');
    /** @var DataHandler $dataHandler */
    $dataHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);
    $dataHandler->BE_USER = $GLOBALS['BE_USER'];
    $dataHandler->BE_USER->user['admin'] = 1;
    $dataHandler->userid = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user['uid'];
    $dataHandler->admin = true;
    $dataHandler->bypassAccessCheckForRecords = true;
    $dataHandler->copyTree = $input->getArgument('recursion');
    $dataHandler->deleteTree = true;
    $dataHandler->neverHideAtCopy = true;
    $dataHandler->start([], $command);
    $dataHandler->process_cmdmap();
    $output->writeln($this->getMessage($dataHandler));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be ok, if we copy the relevant code from your extension to your answer? https://github.com/einpraegsam/migration/blob/master/Classes/Command/DataHandlerCommand.php#L54 It would make the answer more complete and also useful it the code it points to changes or is not available. (This is actually the recommended practice on SO, see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: For sure - copy, change or modify it to your needs - that's open source :D